# Is there a way to bypass the return flow and throw a response.no_content?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hi i am building a springboot application which has lots of rest calls to a third party.
all these rest calls have mappers that map to my models.

If one of these rest calls returns a no-content or created i want to to skip the whole return chain.

If i already know its an empty body is there a way to "throw" a response entity?
Or am i doomed to check in all the mappers and other checks for an empty body?

I feel like i can create a custom exception and throw this with a http 2xx code.

example:

```
   if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful() && !response.hasBody()) {
     // but this one also has an error object body in the response
     throw new ResponseStatusException(response.getStatusCode());
   }
   if (HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.equals(response.getStatusCode())) {
     throw new ResponseStatusException.builder(response.getStatusCode())
```

Any ideas are welcome

Comment: Custom exception should work. You can create a @RestControllerAdvice and catch that exception there, return whatever Http code and body you want. You can refer to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)

Comment: Ah i guess i couldn't just throw an error of type response but your solution was indeed a better one. the intercept just worked Thx!